# Как исправить ошибку Relay access denied postfix?

Tags: python, ubuntu, postfix

Я настроил VPS на отправку почты с помощью Postfix, если тестировать отправку локально на самом VPS, то всё работает, но когда я пытаюсь подключиться удаленно я получаю ошибку
{'email@gmail.com': (454, b'4.7.1 email@gmail.com: Relay access denied')}
Я почитал что ошибка может быть в настройках postfix в параметре mynetworks, я указал его:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.0.0.0/8 [::]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Вот полная конфигурация postfix:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = openfreemail.xyz
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mailemail.xyz, mailer.mailemail.xyz, localhost.mailemail.xyz, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.0.0.0/8 [::]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_use_tls = yes
mynetworks_style = subnet
```

Как я могу исправить конфигурацию для отправки писем, если отправлять на другой адрес на VPS то всё отправляется корректно

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы разрешить доступ всем нужно прописать

```
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 127.0.0.0/8
```